# Is there any content that I shouldn't gzip?

Tags: performance, http, gzip

The Facebook app I am running is on `app.[domain]` domain. All the static content is stored in `/public` path. However, the content is being loaded through a cookie-less alias domain `static.[domain]` host.

Given the present design, it is easy for me to create a copy of all static files, gzip them and use explicitly for serving through `static.[domain]` host.

However, should I exclude any type of file from being gziped? (apart from already gziped content ...)

Comment: Love this question, exactly what I wanted to know, thanks for asking!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, it is a waste of resources to compress data which is already well compressed. Compressing for a second time will gain little to no size difference (or even a slight growth of data in extreme cases), but will cost you and your users extra CPU time for first compressing the data and then decompressing it.

In practice this means you should avoid compressing: most web image formats (JPG, PNG, GIF), almost all A/V multimedia (audio: MP3, OGG, FLAC; video: MPG, MP4, AVI, etc.), and of course common archive formats (ZIP, GZIP, BZ2, RAR, 7ZIP, ARJ, etc.). Also, OpenDocument (.ODF etc.) and new MS Offices files (.DOCX etc.) as well as Java JAR files are internally ZIP archives, so they need no compression, either. SOme PDFs are internally compressed while others are not. Compressing very small files (less than a hundred bytes or so) may also be ineffective depending on the contents.

You could also go in the opposite direction and only explicitly list file types that should be compressed, leaving others without compression. What certainly compresses well is text files: plain text (TXT), HTML, CSS stylesheets, JavaScript (JS) files.

Answer (score 0):

well, any format which already archived in one way or another, like `jpg`, `mp3`, so on.

Comment: This answer, plus http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/payload.html is what I was after.